# Writing mathematical expression for limit on allowed repetitions

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

I have to write the expression explaining, in $0\leq C_1 \leq C_2\leq \cdots \leq C_r$

"There are no more than $l$ numbers (i.e. $C_i$'s) that can have the same value."

How do I write the sentence in double quotes using compact mathematical language?

Comment: $\forall i~ C_i < C_{i+\ell}$

Comment: @JMoravitz That is compact as I wished, though needs a second though to understand.

Comment: @AbuBakar: You can adopt a mixed style, starting with JMoravitz's compact expression and then write "meaning that the sequence cannot remain constant for more than $l$ consecutive terms".